# Why can a variable be formatted, but not an element of an array when using the println macro?

Tags: rust

Say you have

```rust
let x: u8 = 1
println!("{x}");
```

this works fine; however, if you instead have

```rust
let x: [u8; 1] = [1];
println!("{x[0]}");
```

then it throws the error

```
error: invalid format string: expected `'}'`, found `'['
   |
   |         println!("{x[0]}");
   |                   -  ^ expected `}` in format string
   |                   |
   |                   because of this opening brace
   |
   = note: if you intended to print `{`, you can escape it using `{{`
```

why is this?

Answer (score 2):

The inline print functionality is only intended for variable names. To be honest though, I rarely see this syntax used though. Most people prefer `println!("{}", x[0])` instead, and this is one of the main reasons why.

I can defiantly see where they were coming from though. The `{:?}` or `{:X}` syntax might look weird since the colon does not seem to have a use in these statements to print in debug or hexadecimal mode, but I suspect it was made to mirror fields in structs and function arguments. It starts to look more familiar when you write it with the inline variable and spacing: `format!("{name: ?}")`. Under this reasoning it makes more sense to only allow `ident`s here (Token for an identity. Essentially the name of a variable/type/module/etc). But this didn't really materialize (if it ever even was a thing) so we don't have this syntax.

Personally, I think they could have made it work, but you would end up with confusion about how `:?` (and other format specifiers) work in regards to expressions. For example, if people are taught that `{x.foo()}` will print the display of the expression `x.foo()` then does that mean `x.foo(): ?` is also a valid expression? What about `-3.0:3.0?`? It kinda looks like a range in python, but I have just worded it in a confusing way.

**Edit:** Found the RFC for this: https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1618-ergonomic-format-args.html

**Edit 2:** I found a Rust forum post which better addresses your question (https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-allow-arbitrary-expressions-in-format-strings/15812). Their reasoning is as follows:

> - Curly braces in format strings are escaped with curly braces: format!("{{foo}}") prints {foo}. If arbitrary expressions were supported, parsing this would become ambiguous.
> - It's ambiguous when type ascription is enabled: format!("{foo:X}") could mean either type ascription or that the UpperHex trait should be used.
>   The ? operator could be easily confused with Debug formatting: "{foo?}" and "{foo:?}" look very similar.

Comment: "I rarely see this syntax used though" Seconded. Rust programmer going on four years here, and I've literally never seen this before. I just learned about this syntax by reading this answer.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo It was only added in [1.58.0 (2022-01-13)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1580-2022-01-13). So it's new enough that lots of Rust code was written before it existed.

Comment: *To be honest though, I rarely see this syntax used though* - I see it used a lot in our internal code base. The open-source code you see in the wild likely uses it either because was either written prior to the introduction of the syntax or because it still tries to support older Rust versions.

Comment: There is a wish to add field access syntax, but Rust team members have expressed desire to stop there (and BTW, type ascription is being removed now).